# Google Cloud Platform (GCP) JSON Prediction File error on Upload to ML-Predict

Tags: python, json, machine-learning, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I am getting an error on upload of my test data to GCP for prediction. I am simply trying to convert my test data from train_test_split to a json file to run GCP predictions of my deployed model.

**Here is what my dataframe looks like**
[image]

My X_test is all int values. here is my conversion of this dataframe to a newline delimited json file.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_new, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=12, stratify = y) #stratify breaks up our split evenely

    import json

X_test_10 = X_test.head(10) #gets first 10 items for prediction
X_test_10.to_json('test.json') #converts file to json

#creates newline delimited json per google instructions
with open("test.json", "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)
result = [json.dumps(record) for record in data]
with open('nd-proceesed.json', 'w') as obj:
    for i in result:
        obj.write(i+'\n')

#Uploads created json file to GCP model for prediction
!gcloud ai-platform predict --model voluntary_turnover --region us-east1 --json-instances nd-proceesed.json

Using endpoint [https://us-east1-ml.googleapis.com/]
{
  "error": "Prediction failed: Exception during sklearn prediction: could not convert string to float: 'response_count'"
}
```

**Error Message**
"error": "Prediction failed: Exception during sklearn prediction: could not convert string to float: 'response_count'"

I am not sure why I am getting this error since my data is not scaled and I am using the original file/data. Do I need to convert to a numpy array then upload? I am not to sure please help!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this using the code below.

```
import json
X_test_10 = X_test.head(200)#gets first 200 items for prediction
X_test_10_list = X_test_10.values.tolist()
data = {}
data['instances'] = X_test_10_list
    
with open('data_for_prediction.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, indent = 2)
```

Comment: Hi James, I used your code to generate a file but mine sadly fails, as it didn't like that the column names didn't exist in my json file.  How did you solve this?  Also I noticed that you created a txt file whereas only json and csv are acceptable (in Vertex at least)

Comment: hello! just seeing this, is it possible you can tell me what you are trying to do, so i can assist further? i think i understand but want to help with the soloution.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks.  Here's the details of my question: I'm using Vertex ai and trying to get batch predictions.  Using your method I got predictions from a deployed model, but I wanted to have a batch delivery. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67740388/how-to-generate-the-json-format-for-google-cloud-predictions