# how to generate the json format for google cloud predictions

Tags: python, json, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to make predictions from my custom model on Vertex AI but am getting errors.
I have deployed the model to an endpoint and I request prediction using this line

```
gcloud beta ai endpoints predict 1234 --region=europe-west4   --json-request=request2.json
```

and I get this response

```
Using endpoint [https://europe-west4-prediction-aiplatform.googleapis.com/]ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ai.endpoints.predict) FAILED_PRECONDITION: "Prediction failed: Exception during xgboost prediction: feature_names mismatch:
```

I have created the data with this code ( and later renamed to request2.json)

```
test3 = {}
test3["instances"] = test_set2.head(20).values.tolist()
with open('05_GCP/test_v3.jsonl', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(test3, outfile, indent = 2)
```

This generates a file which looks like this.
[image]
The error tells me that its expecting column names  per value instead of nothings, which are then interpreted as f0, f1 etc.

My challenge is that I don't know how to generate data that looks like this( also from the help file)

[image]
Though the result with the mismatched column names suggests I need a different format.

I tried:

```
import json
test4= X_test.head(20).to_json(orient='records', lines=True)
with open('05_GCP/test_v4.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(test4, outfile, indent = 2)
```

which gives me data that looks like:
[image]
ie with many line breaks in it and cloud shell tells me this isn't json.

I also replicated [this format](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/overview#batch_prediction_input_data) and was informed it is not a json file

So 2 questions,

1. how do I create a json file that has the appropriate format for a live prediction.
2. how do I create a jsonl file so I can run batch jobs.  This is actually want I a trying to get to.  I have used csv but it returns errors:

   ('Post request fails. Cannot get predictions. Error: Predictions are not in the response. Got: {"error": "Prediction failed: Could not initialize DMatrix from inputs: ('Expecting 2 dimensional numpy.ndarray, got: ', (38,))"}.', 2)

This csv data is the exact same that I use to measure the model error whilst training (I know not good practise but this is just a test run)

**UPDATE**
Following Raj's suggestion, I tried creating two extra models.  One where I changed my training code to be X_train.values and another where I replaced all the column names to be F0:F426 as the response to the json file on the endpoint said it didn't match column names.

These both SUCCEDDED with the test3 json file above when endpoints where deployed.
However I want this to be returning batch predictions, and here it returns the same errors.  This is therefore clearly a formatting error but I have no clue about how to get there.

it should be pointed out that the batch predictions need to be a jsonl file.  Not a json file.  Trying to pass a json file doesn't work.  All I have done is change the extension on the json file when I loaded it to make it appear as a jsonl file.  I have not found anything that helps me create that.  Tips are welcome.

I noticed that my data was in double brackets.  So I created a version which had only one bracket and ran this on one of the models but it also returned errors.  This was also only one prediction per the other comment.

Appreciate the help,
James

Comment: Did you try to build manually 1 correct entry? If so, what the correct format?

Comment: I don't know what the correct format is. Do you?

Comment: The error could be due to different input formats when model training and model scoring. e.g. using pandas dataframes for training and numpy arrays. If that's the case, you may have to retrain using `df.values`. Another quick way to verify is to set the model feature names as None before saving the model and redeploy the model. `model.feature_names = None`

Comment: @raj I'm going to reply in detail in the question because its too detailed.  But TLDR, creating a model using values or removing the columns SUCCEDED when deploying as an endpoint, but failed when I ran as a batch job

Comment: Hey James, came here from my post, are you still having trouble with this?

Comment: Yep.  Pretty much giving up at this point with GCP unless I can make this work a lot easier.  Recommendations are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

If you train the model with df.values as per raj's answer, you can then pass the instances you want to get batch predictions from in a jsonl file ("input.jsonl" for example) with the following format for each instance/row:

```
    [3.0,1.0,30.0,1.0,0.0,16.1]
```

File would look something like this for 5 rows to predict:

```
    [3.0,1.0,30.0,1.0,0.0,16.1]
    [3.0,0.0,22.0,0.0,0.0,9.8375]
    [2.0,0.0,45.0,1.0,1.0,26.25]
    [1.0,0.0,21.0,0.0,0.0,26.55]
    [3.0,1.0,16.0,4.0,1.0,39.6875]
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Our team have been trying to find the correct format for days :D We have tried with this format but different file name and it didn't work. Strangely, the file extension must be exactly .jsonl with "l" at the end.