# Vertex AI: Batch prediction for custom model fails with RuntimeError: BatchPredictionJob resource has not been created

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

We are trying to run a batch prediction for a custom model.

The training was done after this tutorial:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/vertex-ai-custom-code-training#4

The code to sumbit the job in a pipeline:

```
model = aiplatform.Model(model_path)
batch_prediction_job = model.batch_predict(
    gcs_source=gcs_source,
    gcs_destination_prefix=gcs_destination,
    machine_type='n1-standard-4',
    instances_format='csv',
    sync=False
)
```

Running the batch prediction job fails with the following error in the pipeline:

```
JobState.JOB_STATE_FAILED
[KFP Executor 2023-01-18 14:08:09,862 INFO]: BatchPredictionJob projects/472254905662/locations/us-central1/batchPredictionJobs/3522181183414730752 current state:
JobState.JOB_STATE_FAILED
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kfp/v2/components/executor_main.py", line 104, in <module>
executor_main()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kfp/v2/components/executor_main.py", line 100, in executor_main
executor.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kfp/v2/components/executor.py", line 309, in execute
result = self._func(**func_kwargs)
File "/tmp/tmp.ZqplJAZqqL/ephemeral_component.py", line 23, in create_batch_inference_component
print(f'Batch prediction job "{batch_prediction_job.resource_name}" submitted')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/base.py", line 676, in resource_name
self._assert_gca_resource_is_available()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/base.py", line 1324, in _assert_gca_resource_is_available
else ""
RuntimeError: BatchPredictionJob resource has not been created.
```

There is an error in the failed batch prediction job but it is not possible to understand what it means:

```
Batch prediction job BatchPredictionJob 2023-01-18 14:21:50.490123 encountered the following errors:

Model server terminated: model server container terminated: exit_code: 1 reason: "Error" started_at { seconds: 1674052639 } finished_at { seconds: 1674052640 }
```

Batch prediction for an AutoML model trained for the same Titanic dataset works.

There is no way to troubleshoot this. We have tried different `instance_format`, not specifying `machine_type`, improving the dataset for predictions (the guidelines say all string fields should be enclosed with double quotes) but this hasn't helped.

Comment: Hi @havryliuk, can you provide the sample data and the sample code which you have tried?

Comment: hi @ShipraSarkar, do you mean the whole code with data preparation and model training? I have shared the code with which we submit a batch prediction for the custom model.

Comment: Hi @havryliuk, can you retry with different dataset?

Comment: @ShipraSarkar, we have tried using json in the correct format (instances json) instead of csv because this is a scikit-learn model but the error is the same: `RuntimeError: BatchPredictionJob resource has not been created.`

Comment: Hi @havryliuk, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new [GCP support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: @ShipraSarkar unfortunately our company does not have a support plan. I will create an issue but this will take some time. I will post my answer here if we find a solution or the root cause of the problem. Thank you for your support. In general, there is not much information in Vertex documentation about batch predictions for a custom model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were three issues with this problem that we have managed to solve with our team:

1. We used different containers for training and serving the model. We did not control the scikit-learn version in the container but set its version for model serving. We just installed the required scikit version in the container used for training.
2. We didn't know the correct format of the input for batch predictions. While there is a sample and examples in the documentation for online inference using endpoints, there are no samples of input files for batch prediction. The format is described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68123138/2082681. You just need to pass lines of examples as arrays and (very important) have the source file with .jsonl extension.
3. And finally (!), even after our batch predictions started to work and produce a file with correct predictions, the pipeline which was submitting the batch prediction still failed (!) and with the same error: `BatchPredictionJob resource has not been created.` This was finally fixed by removing `sync=False` passed into `model.batch_predict`.

This took our team (3 people) about three weeks to figure out. Now, the pipeline is green and the batch predictions are working.